# How move a canvas figure when clicked?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have one pentagon figure in canvas, and I want to move it to the place where the mouse is located at a click.

CODE

```
<canvas id="fld" width="1000px" height="800"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    onload = function() { draw(); };
    function draw() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('fld');
      if ( ! canvas || ! canvas.getContext ) {return false;}
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      //Pentagon
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
      ctx.moveTo(100,10);
      for (var i=1;i<=5; ++i) {
        th=i * 2 * Math.PI/5;
        x=100+90*Math.sin(th);
        y=100-90*Math.cos(th);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y);
      }
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(900, 60, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.stroke();
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make a few changes and this will work.

Firstly, you should change your draw() function so that it takes 2 parameters, namely the X and Y position that the figure will be drawn at. Next, you need to change the hard-coded values that you use, so that they are based on the X and Y values that are passed.

Secondly, you should add an onclick handler to the canvas. When you receive a click event, you can get the X and Y coords of the canvas that the mouse was clicked.

You can then clear the canvas and call your updated draw function with the mouse click X and Y.

Look-up onclick handlers for the way to get the position of the mouse when the button is pressed. You'll have to use addEventListener to attach the click handler, so that your function gets the event that triggered it passed to it. You can then extract the co-ords of the click from the event object.